# How to search among my favorite questions

Tags: support, search, bookmarks

As per object. I tried to search among the questions on Meta, but I couldn't find anything (maybe it's also because of limitations  in the mobile site).

Comment: Don't forget to tag your questions appropriately. In this case, for example, it's quite obvious that one should use [search] tag (I edited to put it on).

Comment: @amoeba whoops, you're right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you go to any search field on a Stack Exchange site, you would type `<terms> infavorites:mine` (or more generally, `<terms> infavorites:<user number>` for someone else's favorites).  For more on advanced options for searching SE sites, see the [help page on searching](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/searching).

Here is an example searching for threads about the LASSO in your favorites:
[lasso infavorites:user58675](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=lasso+infavorites%3Auser58675).